# Symmetric inequality for a rational function of three variables

Tags: inequality

If $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers such that $xyz \geqslant 1$ prove: $$\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+xy+y^2}+\dfrac{y^3+z^3}{y^2+yz+z^2}+\dfrac{x^3+z^3}{x^2+xz+z^2} \geqslant 2$$

I have tried with Hölder's inequality, but it is not working. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since:
$$\frac23x^3+\frac13y^3\ge x^y\text{ or }\frac23y^3+\frac13x^3\ge y^2x$$
So:
$$\large x^3+y^3\ge\frac13x^3+\frac23x^2y+\frac23xy^2+\frac13y^3=\frac13(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$$
Hence:
$$\large \sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+xy+y^2}\ge\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y}{3}=\frac23(x+y+z)\ge2\sqrt[3]{xyz}=2$$

Comment: How do you prove $$x^3+y^3 \geqslant x^2y+xy^2$$?

Comment: That's a very basic inequality. If you want to be able to deal with such problems you'll have to learn the basics of inequalities first.

Comment: @chaos see the edit.